# xpath condition select text of one node or another node

Tags: html, xml, xpath

this is my test data

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>foo 1</td>
    <td>first interest</td>
    <td>bar 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo 2</td>
    <td>
      <p>second interest</p>
    </td>
    <td>bar 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'd like to select every time text of second cell (`td[2]`) of table row but problem is that the text can be in another subelement (paragraph `p`).

When I execute this xpath `//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/p/text() | //tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()` the result is ok, but if I execute this for second row `//tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/p/text() | //tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()` then I get three texts where first and last are empty. How can I modify the xpath to get everytime only the text which I'm interested in. Note: there can be also empty cell, that I don't want to get.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPath to get text from required (not empty second) table cells:

```
//tbody/tr/td[2]//text()[normalize-space()]
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the difference between `/text()...` and `//text()...` why two slashes works when one slash does not?

Comment: @bilak `'//td/text()'` - *child* text nodes, `'//td//text()'` - *descendant* text nodes